# Problem about implementation of a stack in C++

Tags: c++, stack

I've to solve an exercise about stacks in C++. I need to implement a Stack class, which support pop() and push() operations. My input is a file input.txt which contains 100 rows. Each row contain 2+N elements: the first one is a string which shows the type, the second one is an int N, which shows the number of elements. Follows the N elements. About output, elements have to be written in an output.txt in reverse order. The generic type H can be an int, a bool, a double and a char. N is an integer between 10 and 200.

Example:

input.txt:

int 5 4 7 8 12 32

char 7 g h t a e d j

double 4 2.78 3.73 4.12 31.92

output.txt:

32 12 8 7 4

j d e a t h g

31.92 4.12 3.73 2.78

I wrote a solution to this problem, compilation is successfull, but when I try to run the program, terminal gives me this error:

malloc(): corrupted top size
Aborted

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> class Stack {
private:
    int top;
    T *arrayStack;
    int size;

public:
    Stack(int len = 200) {
        arrayStack = new T(len);
        top = -1;
        size = len;
    }

    void push(T element) {
        if(top < size-1) {
            top++;
            arrayStack[top] = element;
        }
        else
            return;
    }

    T pop() {
        if(top == -1)
            return -1;
        else {
            top--;
            return arrayStack[top+1];
        }
    }
};

int main() {    
    int intero = 0;
    char carattere = '0';
    bool booleano = true;
    double virgola = 0.00;

    ifstream in("input.txt");
    ofstream out("output.txt");
    int n;
    string tipo;

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        in >> tipo;
        in >> n;
        if(tipo == "int") {
            Stack<int> pila(n);

            for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                in >> intero;
                pila.push(intero);
            }

            for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
                out << pila.pop() << " ";
        }
        else if(tipo == "char") {
            Stack<char> pila(n);

            for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                in >> carattere;
                pila.push(carattere);
            } 

            for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
                out << pila.pop() << " ";
        }
        else if(tipo == "bool") {
            Stack<bool> pila(n);

            for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                in >> booleano;
                pila.push(booleano);
            }

            for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
                out << pila.pop() << " ";

        }
        else if(tipo == "double") {
            Stack<double> pila(n);

            for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                in >> virgola;
                pila.push(virgola);
            }

            for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
                out << pila.pop() << " ";
        }
        out << endl;
    } 
}
```

Comment: `new T(len);` -> `new T[len];`

Answer (score 2):

Use `new T[len]` instead of `new T(len)`.

`new T(len)` creates one instance of `T`, while the constructor of T takes `len` as parameter.

`new T[len]` creates an array of `T` with `len` elements.